# jQuery Cycle and Backstretch usage

Tags: jquery, cycle

I'm try to combine both of these plugins.
Example of usage that I am trying to accomplish is:

```
<ul class="slide">
  <li><img class="bg" src="imageurl"><p>blahblah</p></li>
  <li><img class="bg" src="imageurl2"><p>blahblah</p></li>
</ul>

<script>
 $('.slide').cycle({
   fx: 'fade'
});
$('.slide).backstretch(+$('.bg').attr('src')+);
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Plugins url [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) [Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)

Comment: Cycle and backstretch will usually overwrite any css.

Comment: What is your purpose of backstretch here?

Comment: Backstretch is for fullscreen, http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Comment: Not quite sure why this isn't working, but I made a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QAdzE/

Answer (score 0):

I have "some" solution that works. In general I find the markup not perfect for what you want to achieve. The image has to be hidden manually, which is not a very clean way! I would set an attribute to the

-element or so, that contains the url for backstretch...

Here's my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MBcXT/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function onBefore(curr, next, opts){
        $(next).backstretch($(next).children('img').prop('src'));
    };

 $('.slide').cycle({
     before: onBefore
 });
});
```